# Why does TinyMCE have setTimeout with 0, slowing down the browser?

Tags: javascript, wordpress, tinymce, internet-explorer-11, tinymce-4

I was testing in IE profiler and noticed something really odd that I would think shouldn't happen: The Tinymce.min.js in Wordpress has basically a busy-loop, that can call the resize event (a very expensive operation on this particular page):

```
window.setInterval(function(){var e=window.innerWidth,n=window.innerHeight;(t.w!=e||t.h!=n)&&(t={w:e,h:n},r(window).trigger("resize"))},0)
```

setInterval in general should not be set to 0, and I'm surprised this is in MCE. Doing anything in setInterval will usually use a whole cpu, and bog down the browser. As you can see, it was the main processing going on here when IE11 was being slow:

[image]

Can I turn off this busy-loop by some setting in MCE?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JavaScript TinyMCE/jQuery race condition on firefox](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/346926/javascript-tinymce-jquery-race-condition-on-firefox)

Comment: @PaulSweatte How is an 8 years old question on an old version of TinyMCE relevant to this one, with MCE4?

Comment: [Some](//connect.microsoft.com/IE/feedback/details/1076351/ie-8-11-css-bug-inline-blocks-that-contain-vertical-align-bottom-elements-are-misaligned) [bugs](//connect.microsoft.com/IE/feedbackdetail/view/943864/internet-explorer-xmlhttprequest-fails-to-submit-body-on-redirected-request-request-hangs) [never](//connect.microsoft.com/IE/feedback/details/799913/ie-8-11-ignores-draggable-attribute-when-set-after-mousedown-event-using-settimeout)  [die](//connect.microsoft.com/IE/feedback/details/1653510/edge-ie11-ie10-new-stacking-context-is-not-created-when-opacity-changes-z-index-and-opacity).

Answer (score 0):

There is no option to suppress this, however this issue was fixed in Tinymce 4.3.12 ([fix](https://github.com/tinymce/tinymce/commit/1ba7c80a558b27e5494532e037b488e6b0eece5d#diff-29f0213aa0e63e2060669999f11fa827)). The delay has been changed from 0 to 100.